# Segue with Push animation Right to Left

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, uiviewanimationtransition

I am using this method:

```
[UIView transitionWithView: duration: options: animations: completion:];
```

to control a back animation on a segue. Precisely using this code:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.superview
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
                    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

That works, but what I really want is not a Flip, it is a Push. In other words I want to see the views sliding from right to left, one replacing the other.

Unfortunately there is no UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionPushFromRight.

Therefore my question: how can I get the effect I want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a navigationController, you can do something like this:

```
- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *source = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destination = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

    [source.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                  forKey:kCATransition];

    [source.navigationController pushViewController:destination animated:NO];
}
```

If you don't want to use a `UINavigationController`, and you want the source view controller to go away as opposed to using `presentViewController`, and you don't want the fade out animation caused by using `kCATransitionPush`, then the following solution will work. This also works if your views are transparent and you do not want the containing background to animate.

```
static UIImageView *screenShotOfView(UIView *view)
{
    // Create a snapshot for animation
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImageView *screenShot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenShot;
}

- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destination = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    // Swap the snapshot out for the source view controller
    UIWindow *window = source.view.window;
    UIImageView *screenShot = screenShotOfView(source.view);
    CGRect originalFrame = destination.view.frame;

    BOOL animsEnabled = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    {
        window.rootViewController = destination;
        [window addSubview:screenShot];
        [source.view removeFromSuperview];
        CGRect frame = destination.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x += source.view.bounds.size.width;
        destination.view.frame = frame;
    }
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:animsEnabled];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration
                     animations:^{
                         destination.view.frame = originalFrame;
                         CGRect frame = screenShot.frame;
                         frame.origin.x -= screenShot.bounds.size.width;
                         screenShot.frame = frame;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [screenShot removeFromSuperview];
                     }];   
}
```