# View transition in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, transition

i am using storyboard and want to use push segue when moving from 1 VC to another.

if the normal transition is from left to right, is there any (easy) possible way of changing the VC transition to load from right to left.

i would appreciate it very much if the solution does not have to modal segue.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096864/segue-with-push-animation-right-to-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [custom segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html). You may use it with navigation controller.